# hibernate collection mapping - how can I put the collection owner id as foreign key into a collection's element's table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I have a class `Product` and a class `Part`, where every part can only belong to one one product. Each product has a list of its parts, but a part has no reference to its product.

```
@Entity
@Table (name= "products")
class Product {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "Id")
  int id;

  @Column(name = "Name")
  String name;

  @???
  List<Part> myParts;
```

parts:

```
@Entity
@Table (name= "parts")
class Part {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "Id")
  int id;

  @Column(name = "Name")
  String name;
}
```

In my database the table 'products' does not store information about its parts, but the 'parts' table keeps track of the products in a row 'product_id'.

products:

| id | name |

parts:

| id | name | procuct_id |

I think it is quite normal to have this contrary approaches of the OO- and the ORM "world", but I can't find out how to persist my objects with Hibernate to this structure!

For the one-to-many annotation I only found examples where the part-id would have been stored in the product table.
For many-to-one it seems as if I needed a reference to the product in my parts objects, isn't it?

I hope that I am wrong! ;)

Does anybody know if there is a way to map this without chaning my class or table structure?

( I would be very, very happy if you could explain it with annotations rather than with xml :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean a one-to-many unidirectional mapping, try something as follows:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="product_id")
List<Part> myParts;
```

You can see an example here, [`@OneToMany`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html). Check out "Example 3" in that link.

---

Note: Since you have the `product_id` as foreign key in the `parts` table, it is advised to also have a `Product` type field in the `Part` class.

Comment: oh fine, it works! :)  I had an error in my database...

In which scenario could it be a problem not to have such a field?
I'd really like to avoid it, as it would look quite "ugly" from an OO point of view, doesn't it?! ;)

Comment: @chrissy: It is just an advice. I don't there would be any problem, but for the design point of, you have the a foreign key from product table to parts table in the database, but that relation is really hidden and not reflected by your ORM mapping.